# Reach hook form create inputs dynamically with unic register{} name and id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm creating new inputs dynamically inside an array and each input will have its own `id` and `register{}` name. To do that, I'm using `index` value from `array.map()`.

In `registerTrip()` function I'm trying to add each input value to an array concatenating `counter` number to `data.trip_start_date` to be able to get the corresponding value from the input but this process is not working.

I'm not able to concatenate them even if I convert var `i` to string.

If I `console.log(data.trip_start_date0)` I can get the value but when I `console.log(data.trip_start_date + s)` I get `undefined0`, `undefined1`...

Is this the correct way to do that or I should do it differently?

```
export function RegisterTrips() {

const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, reset } = useForm();
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);


const createDate = () => {
   setCounter(counter + 1);
   console.log(counter);
};

const registerTrip = (data: any) => {

    const formData = new FormData();

    let i;
    let s;
    let trip_start_date;
    const dates = [];
    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

        console.log(i);
        console.log(data.trip_start_date0);
        console.log(typeof (data.trip_start_date0));

        s = i.toString();
        trip_start_date = data.trip_start_date + s;
        // dates.push("trip_start_date", data.trip_start_date.${ i });

        console.log(data.trip_start_date0);
        console.log(trip_start_date);
        // console.log(dates);
     }

}

return(

...

{
    Array.from(Array(counter)).map((e, index) => {
        return (
          <div className = "flex flex-col gap-2 lg:flex-row w-full">

            <div className = "w-full">
          
                <label htmlFor = {`trip_start_date${index}` className = "block mb-2 text-sm text-slate-500"> Trip Date </label>
                    
                <input
                    type = "date"
                    className = "w-full px-2 py-2 text-sm text-slate-600 border border-slate-300 focus:border-slate-400 focus:outline-none rounded-lg"
                    id = {`trip_start_date${index}`}
                    {...register(`trip_start_date${index}`, {required: false})}
                />
            </div>
        )
    })
}

<div className="flex justify-end mt-4 w-full">
   <button type='button' className="text-sm text-blue-500 underline cursor-pointer underline-offset-4 active:text-blue-400" onClick={createDate}>Add new date +</button>
</div>

...

)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `data.trip_start_date + s` you are trying to access the *value* of `data.trip_start_date` (which does not exist) and then concatenate that with `s`. Whereas what you want to do is access the value of `trip_start_date0` (and 1,2,3 etc).

```
trip_start_date = data["trip_start_date" + i.toString()];
```

However, you should be aware for arrays of values you are supposed to use https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usefieldarray.

Comment: Oh, yes. Great! Thanks a lot! I'm going to read the docs to understand it better.